# Why do I get auth'ed when I test hitting my Firebase Cloud Function in a browser?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that handles HTTP requests, using:

```
export const foo = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // etc.
}
```

When I hit the URL for it in a browser, I see a Google sign in page, listing my Google accounts. If I sign in, I then get a 403:

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /foo from this server.
```

Why? There's nothing about this in the docs that I can find. I'm on the free plan ("Spark"), if that makes any difference.

[edit]

I'm accessing the function using the URL:

https://us-central1-[project name].cloudfunctions.net/[function name]

There's no vanity URL.

Comment: The plan you're on should not make a difference. How are you accessing the function? Is through the default `ttps://us-central1-[project-name].cloudfunctions.net/app` URL? Or through a vanity URL mapping on Firebase Hosting?

Comment: How exactly are you getting the URL for this function?

Comment: Oh, I see what's happened. I changed my function name and didn't change the URL, then the auth gave me a false sense that I was indeed hitting my function when in fact I get the same auth from hitting https://us-central1-[project name].cloudfunctions.net/functionThatDoesntExist. Why is that auth there? It's quite confusing.

Comment: Hi @Eliot did you manage to solve the issue? I'm getting the same problem, though I see my custom logs and standard one `Function execution took 127 ms, finished with status code: 302` despite I explicitly do `res.redirect(200)`. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan Yes, answer accepted below. If you're seeing logs from your function, I guess you're hitting your function ;-). Not sure a redirect with status code 200 makes sense. I'd post another question tbh.

Comment: @Eliot found the problem, it was simply a crash after my log statement but I didn't realize that Firebase console doesn't show any stacktrace or so in such case. Once I fixed it, cloud function started to return 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403 message is originating from the main url https://us-central1-[project-name].cloudfunctions.net/ which is fully managed by Google.

It seems cloud functions does not have an error handling for non-existing functions name. Thus everything that is not created are treated the same way as a forbidden link. I don't know if this is an intended behavior but since the functions are running on a [managed](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec) environment, there's not much handling of not existing functions against your project cloud function url.

The following statement from the [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec) above explains it all:

"Cloud Functions run in a fully-managed, serverless environment where Google handles infrastructure, operating systems, and runtime environments completely on your behalf. Each Cloud Function runs in its own isolated secure execution context, scales automatically, and has a lifecycle independent from other functions. "

Hope this helps.